# Java Playing MP4 on top of an existing image

Tags: java, background-image, mp4

I have a stationary image and would like to play various MP4 clips on top of this image with some level of transparency.  are there any examples for this in Java.  I attempted JavaFX and can play the video but I need the image to be present (visible) at all times then I would like to play the video clips on top of the image.  any suggestions/examples?  I have code from an example but it only plays the video.  I need to start with a still image then play the video on top with some transparency:

```
enter code here
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

//goes to user Directory
File f = new File("c:\\tpd\\video.mp4");
Image background = new Image(new 
FileInputStream("c:\\tpd\\Image.jpg"));

//Converts media to string URL
Media media = new Media(f.toURI().toURL().toString());
player = new   javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer(media);
MediaView viewer = new MediaView(player);

//change width and height to fit video
DoubleProperty width = viewer.fitWidthProperty();
DoubleProperty height = viewer.fitHeightProperty();
width.bind(Bindings.selectDouble(viewer.sceneProperty(), "width"));
height.bind(Bindings.selectDouble(viewer.sceneProperty(), "height"));
viewer.setPreserveRatio(true);
ImageView foreground = new ImageView(background);
viewer.setOpacity(.6f);
StackPane root = new StackPane();
root.getChildren().addAll(foreground,viewer);
Scene scene = new Scene(root,1920, 1080, Color.BLACK);
stage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
stage.setScene(scene);
stage.setTitle("myVideo");
stage.show();
player.play();
}
```

Comment: You should show your attempt, so others can see what you've tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: The code runs, the image is in the background and the .mp4 plays on top of it.  I need the image to be set with one function so it is visible, then run another function to play various videos on top of the existing image.